# Type punning in D

Tags: d

I'm attempting to translate the infamous [fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) technique to the D programming language from C. A necessary step involves storing long bits in an integer:

```
i  = * ( long * ) &y;
```

In the comments section, Andrew suggests that this operation is called type punning. **Does anyone know how to perform a type pun operation in D?**

For those who are curious, here's a complete C representation of the code:

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number ) {
long i;
float x2, y;
const float threehalfs = 1.5F;
x2 = number * 0.5F;
y  = number;
i  = * ( long * ) &y;    // the part in question
i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );
y  = * ( float * ) &i;   // again, but for floating points
y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );
return y;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly the same thing in D as in C? It should work... (well, other than C long is slightly different, you'd use a D `int` for `float`)

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I'll test and respond. How do people typically refer to the operation used?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Unfortunately, the \*(<type>\*) syntax seems to throw a parse error. Do you by any chance know the name of that operation?

Comment: What you're trying to do is called "type punning". Be careful doing this in C - if you don't follow the strict aliasing rules, you'll invoke undefined behavior. I don't know the D language semantics for type punning, but it's something that ought to be well documented in the language reference material.

Comment: Oh, D requires the keyword `cast` before the parens. So like `* cast( int *) & y;`

Comment: Casting from int to float or vice versa is always undefined behavior in C. The only way to do this in a defined way, is to use memcpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really needed to do was to use the D-style casting - that is the only place where D code differs from the C one.

Here is the working program:

```
import std.stdio;

float Q_rsqrt(float number) {
  int i;  // we use int here because int.sizeof == float.sizeof
  float x2, y;
  const float threehalfs = 1.5F;
  x2 = number * 0.5F;
  y  = number;
  i  = * cast(int*) &y;
  i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );
  y  = * cast(float*) &i;
  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );
  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 2nd iteration

  return y;
}

int main() {
  writeln(Q_rsqrt(0.15625f));
  // Output: 2.52981

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The same can be achieved with `union`, with the added benefit that now it can be made `@safe` and is a bit easier on eyes:

```d
float Q_rsqrt(float number) @safe {
  union V {
    int i;
    float y;
  }
  V v;
  float x2;
  const float threehalfs = 1.5F;
  x2 = number * 0.5F;
  with (v) {
    y  = number;
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 2nd iteration
    return y;
  }
}

int main() {
  writeln(Q_rsqrt(0.15625f));
  // Output: 2.52981

  return 0;
}
```

With optimizations on, it generates the same assembly as the implementation with pointer casts (at least in LDC and GDC).